# .htaccess subdomain redirect with variables

Tags: .htaccess, url, variables, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a way to have an url like

> -cbbbc.example.com

redirect to

> example.com/something/maybesomethingelse/-cbbbc

So **$.example.com** should redirect to **example.com/1/2/$**

Normally you would just take everything before example.com and redirect it to the other place. But I do have admin.example.com and otherstuff.example.com that I don't want to redirect, because they already have other redirects in place.

the variable before example.com could be anything, the only rule it has is it starts with a certain character "-" in this case, has a specific number of characters (5 in this case) and is never one of the predetermined names (like for example admin, logout, login, etc.)

Is there a way to make a htaccess rule that takes all of these criteria and redirects according to them?

Plus: A bonus would be if -cbbbc.example.com could redirect to example.com/1/2/cbbbc, without the dash. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^admin\.example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^login\.example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^logout\.example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   -(.{5})\.example.com
RewriteRule (.*)  http://example.com/something/maybesomethingelse/-%1
```

I did not test it but I think it works!let me know if not!

Comment: wow.... just for giving me such a beautiful and clean example I'm gonna give you a +1... Will test asap.

Comment: somehow, the new .htacces makes links like cbbbc.example.com go to example.com/cbbbc. Could this be because I also use a line to remove index.php from the url?

Comment: @xaddict put that line here pls!

Comment: RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: But I have also tried removing this and it still doesn't work... I;ve sent my provider an email asking if they have any custom stuff in the DNS that could create this problem

Comment: @xaddict I don't understand how it can remove index.php?

Comment: Me neither... I haven't had any useful replies though. I think there's a rule somewhere that alters things but I'm fairly sure your snippet would work if I somehow manage to disable this behaviour.

Comment: can you put .htaccess file here?

Comment: I've figured out. It had something to do with an automatic catch-all address.